# systemd as a bypass of pam_wheel configuration

Tags: systemd, su

Restricting `su` so it only works for a subset of user logins sounds like a  nice way to harden security.  This is what `pam_wheel` is for.

> ### Examples
>
> The root account gains access by default (rootok), only wheel members
>   can become root (wheel) but Unix authenticate non-root applicants.
>
> ```
> su      auth     sufficient     pam_rootok.so
> su      auth     required       pam_wheel.so
> su      auth     required       pam_unix.so
> ```

`systemd-run` (and `machinectl`, as it mentions in the `man` page) allows running commands as root.  It uses PolicyKit for authentication/authorization.  It does not open a pam session.

So... now the big distros are all defaulting to systemd, what is the equivalent configuration to pam_wheel, for these `systemd` methods?

For full hardening, this may apply to a few other services.  Some libvirt operations are only available as root.  So by default I'm suspicious that this is not too different from Docker.  Granting access to the Docker daemon (the socket file it reads requests from) is equivalent to root access, with very little work required.

If this is not as simple to set up as pam_wheel, is there some convenient automation available to apply it?  Personally I'm already using Ansible for some automation, but I'm interested in any available scripts as examples.

Comment: Equivalent to what? How are you using `pam_wheel` here? `required` or `sufficient` or something else?

Comment: As in the manpage example; an extra `required`.  It's less obvious how you would use `sufficient` to _increase_ security :-P.

Comment: It's not difficult to think of setups where you have scripts from a system user  `su`ing to another user as needed. Since you're using `su` anyway instead of the far more flexible `sudo`, it stands to reason your setup could be far more insane than is usual.

Comment: Sorry, you had a perfectly valid question.  I don't use `su`, but I'm looking at some supported way to disable it, at least for some users.  My understanding is `pam_wheel` is the go-to method.